# Click events on buttons over google maps div?

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I’m trying to put a html button over the native cordova google maps div.

The problem is that the layer of the map is requesting focus continuously.

If I use the “setClickable(false)” event the buttons works correctly but the map is not usable.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the buttons *inside* of the div where the map is, like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Map Demo</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="action-buttons">
            <button color="primary" ion-button text-only>
                Button 1
            </button>
             <button color="primary" ion-button text-only>
                Button 2
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

And then place them where you want by setting the position of the container, to be an `absolute` value:

```
.action-buttons {
    display: block;
    width: calc(100% - 16px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 16px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 999;

    button {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px;
    }
}
```